# __gnu_Unwind_backtrace и Android NDK, ошибка линковки

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

Я пытаюсь распечать коллстэк внутри обработчика сигнала на Android. К сожалению стандартный _Unwind_backtrace умеет печатать только текущий коллстэк, а не тот, который был в момент получения сигнала.

```
typedef struct
{
  _uw demand_save_flags;
  struct core_regs core;
} phase2_vrs;

extern "C" _Unwind_Reason_Code __gnu_Unwind_backtrace(_Unwind_Trace_Fn trace, void * trace_argument, phase2_vrs * entry_vrs);


static _Unwind_Reason_Code unwindCallback(struct _Unwind_Context* context, void* arg)
{
    BacktraceState* state = static_cast<BacktraceState*>(arg);
    uintptr_t pc = _Unwind_GetIP(context);
    if (pc) {
        if (state->current == state->end) {
            return _URC_END_OF_STACK;
        } else {
            *state->current++ = reinterpret_cast<void*>(pc);
        }
    }
    return _URC_NO_REASON;
}

size_t captureBacktrace(void** buffer, size_t max, void *arg)
{
    ucontext_t* signal_context = (ucontext_t*) arg;

    phase2_vrs pre_signal_state = {};
    pre_signal_state.core = *reinterpret_cast<const core_regs*>(&(signal_context->uc_mcontext.arm_r0));

    BacktraceState state = {buffer, buffer + max};

    __gnu_Unwind_backtrace(unwindCallback, &state, &pre_signal_state);

    return state.current - buffer;
}
```

Но получаю ошибку линковки:

```
error: undefined reference to '__gnu_Unwind_backtrace'
```

Я пытался прилинковать `libgcc`, но это ничего не дало.
Я использую Android NDK r10d (64-bit), тулчейн arm-linux-androideabi-4.8

Comment: Не тот SO. Или переводите на рус., или постите на англ.

Comment: @metalurgus каюсь, моя вина